# Cookie store with toggleClass

Tags: html, jquery, cookies

I have cookies on my site, so whenever the user clicks on 'bookmark', this will then add the class 'bookmarked' that will simply make this a different colour.

Could someone please show where I am going wrong? I want so whenever the user refreshes the page, it simply adds the class to the .bookmark class that they have previously clicked.

Also, I want that if they click the class 'bookmarked' this then removes the cookie for that. As they no longer want to book mark this.

HTML

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/js-cookie/2.1.3/js.cookie.js"></script>

<ul>
    <li><div class="bookmark">Star</div></li>
    <li><div class="bookmark">Star</div></li>
    <li><div class="bookmark">Star</div></li>   
</ul>
```

CSS

```
<style>.bookmarked {background:red;}</style>
```

JQuery

```
 <script>
 $(".bookmark").each(function () {
     if (Cookies.get($(this))) {$(this).addClass('bookmarked');}
 });

$('.bookmark').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).toggleClass('bookmarked');
    Cookies.set('bookmark-' + $('.bookmark').index(this), 'bookmarked', { expires: 365 });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, note that your use of `$(this)` in the `get()` method of the cookie is incorrect. You need to use the index of the `.bookmark` element which can be retrieved through the first argument provided to `each()`.

```
$(".bookmark").each(function(i) {
  if (Cookies.get('bookmark-' + i)) {
    $(this).addClass('bookmarked');
  }
});

$('.bookmark').on('click', function(e) {
  $(this).toggleClass('bookmarked');
  Cookies.set('bookmark-' + $(this).index('.bookmark'), 'bookmarked', {
    expires: 365
  });
});
```

That being said, it appears as though the cookie library you're using no longer works. In all other instances you're following the [documentation they provide](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie) and no cookies are being created. Even a basic `Cookies.add('foo', 'bar')` does nothing.

As a workaround I would suggest you create the functionality you require using localStorage instead:

```js
$(".bookmark").each(function(i) {
  if (localStorage.getItem('bookmark-' + i)) {
    $(this).addClass('bookmarked');
  }
});

$('.bookmark').on('click', function(e) {
  let $this = $(this).toggleClass('bookmarked');
  if ($this.hasClass('bookmarked')) {
    localStorage.setItem('bookmark-' + $this.index('.bookmark'), 'bookmarked');
  } else {
    localStorage.removeItem('bookmark-' + $this.index('.bookmark'));
  }
});
```

[**Example jsFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/kquL1fjn/)

Comment: Hi Rory, thanks for your help! For now I will use via localstorage. Just one quick question, if the bookmark has already got the class 'bookmarked'. If I click this again to remove the toggle, on refresh this is still showing with the class. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: You're right - I just updated the answer to fix that issue by calling `removeItem`

Comment: Brilliant thanks alot Rory for your help! Greatly appreciated